# Access a jtable from another class

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have found similar items but I just can't grasp the concept on how to do it. I have a class called HealthTracker which contains a JTable. Then I have another class called SQL that has all my sql releated methods. One of those methods is called populateTable. I can do my query etc but I can't figure out how to access the JTable located in the HealthTracker class from my SQL class. Here is the code from my SQL class.

```
public void populateTable(int qryType){ 
    try{
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
           @Override
           public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
              return false;
           }
        };

        Connection dbconn = SQL.dbConn();
        Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();

        String qry = "SELECT * FROM Services";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

        int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();            
        for (int col = 1; col <= numCols; col++){
            tblModel.addColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(col));
        }

        int row = 0;
        while (rs != null && rs.next()){
            tblModel.addRow(new Object[0]);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("ServiceID"), row, 0);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("Institution"), row, 1);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("Comments"), row, 2);
            row++;
        }   
        rs.close(); 

        // This is the line that gives me the error
        HealthTracker.this.tblMain.setModel(tblModel);

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is great, however I still need to be able to access that JTable from other classes. See this code happens when the application first loads to initialize the table, but the user needs to be able to filter the data. So I created a filter button that displays another window (SearchRecord.java class) where the user can enter their parameters and then click find. Once that "find" button is clicked then I run the query and the table should be reloaded with the new results. Maybe am approaching this the wrong way?

```
public class SearchRecord {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtInstitution;
    private JTextField txtStartDate;
    private JTextField txtEndDate;

    //  Launch the application
    public static void searchForm() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SearchRecord window = new SearchRecord();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //  Create the application
    public SearchRecord() {
        initialize();
    }

    //  Initialize the contents of the frame
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 462, 180);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Search Parameters");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        label.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel lblInstitution = new JLabel("Institution: ");
        lblInstitution.setBounds(10, 47, 85, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblInstitution);
        lblInstitution.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblInstitution.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));

        txtInstitution = new JTextField();
        txtInstitution.setBounds(98, 45, 326, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtInstitution);
        txtInstitution.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblStartDate = new JLabel("Start Date: ");
        lblStartDate.setBounds(10, 78, 85, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblStartDate);
        lblStartDate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblStartDate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));

        txtStartDate = new JTextField();
        txtStartDate.setBounds(98, 76, 175, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtStartDate);
        txtStartDate.setColumns(10);

        JButton button = new JButton("...");
        button.setBounds(283, 76, 25, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("...");
        button_1.setBounds(283, 106, 25, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button_1);

        JLabel lblEndDate = new JLabel("End Date: ");
        lblEndDate.setBounds(10, 109, 85, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEndDate);
        lblEndDate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblEndDate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));

        txtEndDate = new JTextField();
        txtEndDate.setBounds(98, 107, 175, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtEndDate);
        txtEndDate.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnFind = new JButton("Find");
        btnFind.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnFind.setBounds(354, 106, 70, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnFind);

        //  Find Records
        btnFind.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                //  Gather all the fields from form
                String[] fields = new String[3];
                fields[0] = txtInstitution.getText();
                fields[1] = txtStartDate.getText();
                fields[2] = txtEndDate.getText();

                //  Refresh Table w/Filtered Data from DB
                SQL loadTbl = new SQL();
                try{
                    HealthTracker.this.tblMain.setModel(loadTbl.populateTable(0));
                } catch (SQLException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `populateTable` method return the instance of the `TableModel` rather than having it trying to apply the model to an instance of `JTable`

```
public TableModel populateTable(int qryType) throws SQLException{ 
    DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
       @Override
       public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
          return false;
       }
    };
    String qry = "SELECT * FROM Services";
    try (Connection dbconn = SQL.dbConn(); 
        Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry)) {

        int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();            
        for (int col = 1; col <= numCols; col++){
            tblModel.addColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(col));
        }

        int row = 0;
        while (rs != null && rs.next()){
            tblModel.addRow(new Object[0]);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("ServiceID"), row, 0);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("Institution"), row, 1);
            tblModel.setValueAt(rs.getString("Comments"), row, 2);
            row++;
        }   
    }
    return model;
}
```

This means that the method has one job, load the `TableModel`, that's it.  It also means that you can call it when ever and however you like

Comment: This is great, however I still need to be able to access that JTable from other classes. See this code happens when the application first loads to initialize the table, but the user needs to be able to filter the data. So I created a filter button that displays another window (SearchRecord.java class) where the user can enter their parameters and then click find. Once that "find" button is clicked then I run the query and the table should be reloaded with the new results. Maybe am approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: So? Why can't you load another instance of the class which is doing the querying when you need it? BUT, you could take advantage of `JTable`s built in filtering support, see [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details

Comment: I guess I am doing it the wrong way because I can't make that code that I just added work. I apologize for my ignorance, but this is my first project on java. I have never done java before.

Comment: Based on your updated code, `SearchRecord` should gather the search parameters from the user and return that back to the caller (I'm assuming `HealthTracker`) - See [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for a better solution.  This would allow `HealthTracker` to then call you "database utilities" class, which contains the `populateTable` method with the value from the `SearchRecord`.  Seperation of responsibilities